# Why can't I tag multiple people in my comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Sometimes, I have a typo or some sort of mistake in my questions / answers / comments. Then all of a sudden, there will be several people telling me that there's been a mistake (no complaints here..).. The problem is I cannot tag multiple people in a comment. So, I'll have to tag each person individually (and sometimes, this is kind of frustrating.).

My request : In a comment please allow me to tag multiple people. Something like this :

> @Mr X, @Mr, Y @Ms Z - yes, this can be done in a different and more efficient way but my way of solving this problem has the following advantages....

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to tell them you agree with them in the first place?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - edited my question.. I can have the same response for 3 different people right?

Comment: @TheLostMind If the question is active, chances are they'll all see your response to one of them. Otherwise, I just wouldn't worry about it. The people notifying you of the mistake _probably aren't worrying about it_ and have very likely moved on or already forgotten about it. If they were worried, and come back to check, they'll see the other comments.

Comment: Here's the cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85771/is-single-comment-to-notify-several-users-a-reasonable-idea.  Actually this is a more thorough one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - We can't just bank on chance... can we?.  It could be a down-vote, a suggestion etc. I could agree with them or disagree with them.. That's not the point.. The point is , I find it tedious to write multiple comments saying the same thing.. For people like Jon Skeet, Bohemian, Boris the spider or yourself.. You might comment on scores of posts and then totally forget about them.. right?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral things. All your comments could go away tomorrow.  This comment I'm writing now could go away at any point.  That's why vital information goes into the answer or to the question. Everything else is a post-it note at the mercy of the wind.

Comment: @TheLostMind Yes it's true, I comment on lots and lots of posts and forget about a good portion. But if it's a question of interest to me, or the OP was actively engaged in the comment thread I tend to keep it open. That's me though.

Comment: SE took strong counter-measures to prevent the comment feature from turning into a chat room.  Not being able to address more than one user was quite intentional.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I agree.. but I just can't add something to my answer just because some people down-vote it and say that there is a better way.. I would first like to know what they want to say.. For comments like - *don't use regex here, use normal string methods*, I would first like to see their side of the story before updaing / deleting/ changing my answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I agree.. but if you leave a comment saying that something could be done in a different way and then forget it??.. assume 3 other people do the same thing.. Now, should I comment 4 times?

Comment: @HansPassant - I know that it was *intentional*.. If you don't want the comment feature to turn into a chat room, then allow us to tag multiple people in a single comment.. This reduces the number of comments.. :P

Comment: @TheLostMind No, I don't think you should comment 4 times. Comment once, probably to the first person who pointed it out. You don't really owe anyone anything. If you are trying to reverse downvotes, you may take a different approach, but really I wouldn't worry about it just to let commenters know you incorporated their suggestions.

Comment: @George currently "comments are  ephemeral" but does that mean they should be going forward?

Comment: @Hans Does preventing a commenter from addresses multiple commenters/comments really affect whether comments are too chatty or not?

Comment: More generally, comments are not first class questions or answers but can be useful in the long term refinement and contextualization of both questions and answers. Treating them as worthless and hindering their use does a disservice to the quality of information about the questions and answers on SE.

Comment: @jball Yes. Can you imagine this comment thread being useful to future visitors for eternity? For all intents and purposes, this comment thread is obsolete now (everyone who has asked a question has received a comment with their answer or clarification).

Comment: @George, I disagree fundamentally, and you've been around long enough that you should have seen amazing comments and comment threads to internally examine against my claim, but if you desire, I can spend more text on this comment thread proving the obvious.